# can anyone explain how this programm runs in sequence?

Tags: c++, oop

I dont understand how the room and clock constructors are called

> when we call postoffice constructor and what will be the order of
> constructors and destructors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Clock{
    int HH, MM;
public :
    Clock():HH(0), MM(0){
        cout<<"Constructor Clock "<<endl;
    }
    Clock(int hh,int mm): HH(hh), MM(mm){
        cout<<"constructor clock at "<<hh<<mm<<endl;
    }
    ~Clock(){
        cout<<"Destructor Clock"<<endl;
    }
};

class Room{
    Clock clock;
public:
    Room(){
        cout<<"Constructor room"<<endl;
    }
    ~Room(){
        cout<<"Destructor room"<<endl;
    }
};

class Postoffice{
    Clock clock;
    Room room;
public:
    Postoffice(){
        clock=Clock(18,30);
        cout<<"Constructor postoffice"<<endl;
    }
    ~Postoffice(){
        cout<<"Destructor postoffice"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Postoffice p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your debugger can explain that well. Just use it to step through your code line by line.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sequence of events during initialization of `p`:

1. `Postoffice::Postoffice()` is called. Before the body of the function is entered, the initializers of all members of `Postoffice` run in the order of declaration.
2. `Clock::Clock()` is called to initailize `Postoffice::clock`.
3. `Room::Room()` is called. Similar to 1. the member variables are called resulting in `Clock::Clock()` running for `Room::clock`.
4. The body of `Room::Room()` runs.
5. The body of `Postoffice::Postoffice()` runs and `clock=Clock(18,30);` is executed. This first creates a temporary `Clock` object that is move assigned to the `Postoffice::clock`. At the end of this expression the temporary `Clock` object gets destroyed (`Clock::~Clock()` call).
6. Print from `Postoffice::Postoffice()`.

At the end of the `main` function `p` goes out of scope resulting in:

1. The destructor body `Postoffice::~Postoffice()` runs.
2. After the completion of the destructor body the member variables of `Postoffice` are destroyed in reverse order resulting so the body of `Room::~Room()` running.
3. After the body completes, the destructor `Clock::~Clock()` is run for `Room::clock`
4. With the destruction of `Postoffice::room` completed `Postoffice::clock` gets destroyed running `Clock::~Clock()`.